# LVM partition "Not available"?

Tags: linux, lvm

I have a disk that I took out of a failed system.  One of the partitions on the disk was one half of a software RAID-1, and that RAID-1 was a lvm2 volume group.  There are several logical volumes on that volume group.  Thanks to [this answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/179353/how-do-i-mount-one-half-of-a-software-raid-1/179366#179366) I got the RAID-1 mounted and the volume group seen and recognized.  I can mount most of the partitions and back them up, but one of them (of course the one I care about the most) won't mount.  The system crashed while I had a snapshot partition snapshotting this partition for a backup, but I've now removed that snapshot.  lvdisplay reports:

```
lvdisplay -v /dev/xen-disk/xen1-disk
    Using logical volume(s) on command line
  --- Logical volume ---
  LV Name                /dev/xen-disk/xen1-disk
  VG Name                xen-disk
  LV UUID                li3NC9-jRwg-ndbM-oplJ-1Omd-PcX9-qv9aB2
  LV Write Access        read/write
  LV Status              NOT available
  LV Size                150.00 GB
  Current LE             38400
  Segments               1
  Allocation             inherit
  Read ahead sectors     0
```

How do I repair whatever is making this unavailable and get it mounted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you get any luck with:

`lvchange -a y /dev/xen-disk/xen1-disk`

?

Comment: how do avoid having to run this every reboot?

Comment: Rebuild you initial ramdisk. That handles LVM activation on boot.